# Use Apache as a proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, reverse-proxy

I need to setup an linux/apache box to be a proxy for an IIS web server running a .NET application.

I need no checks, verifications, modifications, nothing.  I want to point the A record for www.mydomainname.com to the linux/apache server and have it relay any URL for http://mydomainname.com to the IP address of the IIS web server.

Note that I *cannot* relay to another domain name.  I must relay to the IIS IP address.

Additionally, it has to work if someone goes to:
http://*.mydomainname.com 
or
http://mydomainname.com/*

linux/apache should simply pass the requested URL directly to the IIS server, no matter what that URL is.  It would be nice if it was only for the domain "mydomainname.com" - but if it had to be a complete wildcard, that's okay.  There is only one domain which will be pointed to our linux/apache server, and it should forward any URL thrown at it to ONE IP address.

I have struggled with many other examples, but they are doing exceptions, exemptions, re-writes, renames, etc.

I need a very simple, basic "proxy" to another IP address.  That's all.

Thank you for the help!!!

Answer (score 2):

see the documentation for mod_proxy here: [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html), including a reverse proxy exmaple  Sounds like you'll want the ProxyPreserveHost option turned on.